# Auto-change class-name by using while

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

I want to know, if there is a way in Python to create an class/thread like

```
class testthread1(Thread):
    def run(self):
        print("Hello World")
```

by using a while loop, so that testthread1 automatically changes to testthread2?

Comment: Actually you are not creating a thread with the code from above. You are defining a class and instances of that class belong to different threads. You can just create many instances with something like `threads = [testthread1() for i in range(10)]`.

Comment: Hae, but if i so dtestthread1 = dttestthread()
dtestthread1.start() after my code what is it then if not a thread xd?

Comment: Or even better question, then how can i do my code that I posted create automatically with an different number at the end?

Comment: Like `[globals()[f"testthread{i}"]() for i in range(1,3)]`?